# Erlang: How does processes mailboxes relates to the scheduler run-queue?

Tags: process, erlang, queue

I'm new to Erlang. As far as I know:

- A VM has one or more (SMP mode) schedulers.
- A scheduler has exactly one message run queue

Also:

- A process has an 'internal' mail box, for incomming messages

Since a private mailbox seems to be local to a process, how does it relate to the 'global' scheduler run queue? Are they the same, e.g. is a mail box a small subset of the scheduler run queue? If not, how do they relate to each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process has a message queue. A scheduler has *process* run queues, not *message* run queues. Schedulers run processes, and a process receives messages from its message queue.